# Why does devenv.exe invoke VS2008's installer when called from an MSBuild script?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I have this nice little MSBuild-based daily build setup that I use on my personal projects. It checks out my code, builds it, then invokes devenv.exe on my project to build my VS setup project.

It has always worked swimmingly, until, well, yesterday. Now, whenever it tries to invoke devenv.exe, the VS 2008 installer comes up, and I have to physically click "Cancel" to make it go away, at which point, the build resumes and finishes without any problems.

The only difference between before, when it worked, and after, when it stopped working, is that I traveled to a different location and am using a different wireless network.

Here is part of my script:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudio9>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"</VisualStudio9>
    <StagingPathBetaPro>BetaPro</StagingPathBetaPro>
    <CheckoutPathBetaPro>CheckoutTrunk</CheckoutPathBetaPro>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BetaPro">

    <!-- snip -->

    <Exec Command="$(VisualStudio9) $(StagingPathBetaPro)\$(CheckoutPathBetaPro)\MyProject.sln /Build Release-Beta-Pro /Project Setup-Beta-Pro"/>

    <!-- snip -->

  </Target>
</Project>
```

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you open that solution in Visual Studio? Does the installer popup?

Comment: No, the installer does not pop up if I open it in Visual Studio. I can build the setup project from Visual Studio, too, and have it complete successfully without the installer popping up.

Comment: What if you just execute the command itself rom the command line? I would be pretty surprised to find out that this is related to MSBuild.